# jquery WebService responseXML / responseText

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, xmldocument

I get an empty response back from this local WebService call via jquery / ajax.

I have verified the URL and XML input string by invoking the call in a browser. 
I DO get XML code back as expected.

What am I missing? Could it have something to do with the return type "XmlDocument"?
I have tried changing out text/xml to text. No affect. Tried a GET instead of POST.

---

Webservice (running locally)...

_
Public Function GetXML(ByVal strXML As String) As XmlDocument...
Dim retXML As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

...CODE....

Return retXML

---

Calling Function:

#

GetStat() {

var Url = 'http://localhost/myService.asmx?op=GetXML';

var msg = '
 
  
    55
    POPE
    myUser
    myPwd
  
 
';

```
$.ajax({
    url: Url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text/xml",
    data: msg,
    complete: processResult,
    contentType: "text/xml"
});

return false;
```

}

function processResult(xmlData, status) {
    var jData = $(xmlData);
}

#

Thanks!

Comment: var msg in example was supposed to be a valid XML string. It was truncated during post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see that the [XML is well formed](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)?

Other than that i'm pretty sure `contentType` should be `"xml"`.

Comment: Hansen, you are partially correct. I changed the dataType: "jsonp" and at least am seeing data come back. However, now I get "unterminated regular expression leteral".